# Select the row with max value in one column value and min value in another

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want to SELECT the row with max value in NumofTrips also with min value in NumofVehicle.

Comment: Are these column names of same table?

Comment: What if the max and min values are in different rows?

Comment: Could you replace the image with plain text? It's hard to read your image because there's something shaded behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what I need!!!

SELECT id, Base, Basename, NumofTrips / NumofVehicle AS pickup
FROM FHV
ORDER BY pickup DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would make my SELECT query FROM whatever table and then  ORDER BY NumofTrips, then ORDER BY NumofVehicle. You may need to reverse them as you see fit to get them in the right order.

On a completely different note. When it comes to naming, your table fields should be named numOfTrips and numOfVehicle, or simply numTrips and numVehicle, following camelCase naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am totally new to mysql... Thank you for the naming suggestion also!

Comment: Just figured out a better way  SELECT id, Base, Basename, NumofTrips / NumofVehicle AS pickup
FROM FHV
ORDER BY pickup DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

Get single row return from each query

```
SELECT max(NumOfTrips) FROM table_name

SELECT min(NumOfVehicles) FROM table_name
```